# Top navigation bar (categories) not showing

Tags: magento, navigation, categories

I am using a theme called bootstrapped (`http://bootstrapped.magenthon.com/`)for my Magento project. This theme has somehow removed the top navigation bar. When I checked the file -

> template/page/html/header.phtml

I found this line was commented out -
`<?php //echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>`

I tried uncommenting it, but the top navigation bar still didn't show up. I have tried editing `page.xml` and `local.xml` and yet nothing has worked.

I have also tried adding the code directly from `topmenu.phtml` to `header.phtml`, assuming that the file `topmenu.phtml` is somehow not being included when building the frontend and yet top menu doesn't show up.

Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Exactly the same problem here.Any help??

Comment: Hi, try flushing cache storage. Are you using the same theme?